# Git - files checkout status, checkout by others

Tags: git, azure-devops

VSTS has this amazing feature, using TFS Power Tools, you can see if someone else has edited a file, that was not commited.

this is great in projects where (some) files cannot be merged.

Does a feature like this exist for Git? (or any third party tools.)

I Have Googled, and Bing'ed a lot searching anything related to 'checkout status' , not finding this feature.

Comment: `Does a feature like this exist for Git?` No.

Comment: The basic concept of git is decentralized. Each copy of a repository is completely independent of each other. No connection to any server or any other service is required. Therefore a feature like this is neither possible nor meaningful by git's design.

Comment: Can you really do this, "you can see if someone else has **edited** a file, that was not commited"? Or are you referring to the VSTS feature where you can see if someone has checked out (locked) that file, which only means they might edit it, but doesn't show if they did in fact edit it?